# Alternative piece movement on a 10x10 board in C

Tags: c

I am trying to make the pieces on my board move from left to right and then right to left whenever it moves up a line on the board. I am using 2D arrays to represent the coordinates and pointer arithmetic to manipulate it since we cannot use 2D arrays on the function itself.

```
while (k <= 11) { //I used K as a marker for the 11 vertical line Im going to make
  if (lineOne == 1) {
    printf("|");
    lineOne = 0;
    lineTwo = 1;
    k++;
  } else if (lineTwo == 1) {
    if (row % 2 == 0) { //pointer arithmetic to go through each part of the array
      printf("%c%c%c%c", *( * (arrA + row) + col), 
                         *( * (arrB + row) + col), 
                         *( * (arrC + row) + col),
                         *( * (arrD + row) + col));
      col++;
    } else if (row % 2 != 0) {
      printf("%c%c%c%c", *( * (arrA + row) + col),
                         *( * (arrB + row) + col),
                         *( * (arrC + row) + col),
                         *( * (arrD + row) + col));
      col--;
    }
    lineOne = 1;
    lineTwo = 0;
  }
}

row++;
divider = 1;
thirdLine = 0;
printf("\n");
```

These are my initializations

```
int row = 0, col = 0;
```

In my head as well, my 2D grid is arranged like this

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

This is the output of my code. Dont mind the S, its a bug for another day :(

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|#   |S   |S   |S   |S   |S   |S   |S   |S   |S   |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|-   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
a's turn.
a, press <Enter> to roll.

You rolled a 5

95

95
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|#   |S   |S   |S   |S   |S   |S   |S   |S   |S   |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    |a   |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+

95

get out
b's turn.
b, press <Enter> to roll.
```

Here 9 5 are the coordinates I have for that player

As you can see a moved 5 steps to the left when it was supposed to do it from left to right like this

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|#   |   S|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |    |    |l   |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |l   |   S|    |    |    |    |    |   s|    |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |    |L   |    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |l   |    |    |L   |S   |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |    |   s|    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |   s|L   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|abcd|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+

a's turn.
a, press <Enter> to roll.

+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|#   |   S|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |    |    |l   |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |l   |   S|    |    |    |    |    |   s|    |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |    |L   |    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |l   |    |    |L   |S   |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |    |   s|    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |   s|L   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
| bcd|    |    |    |   a|    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+

a rolls a 4!
b's turn
b, press <Enter> to roll.
```

I just want my pieces to move alternately for each time they move up a Y-axis.

Comment: How much debugging did you do? https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ Please provide a [mre] to demonstrate your observation.

Comment: I've reformatted the code to make it easier to read and see similarities. Note how there's duplicate printf inside of the `(row % 2 == 0)` test. Perhaps you would want to move the printf before the `if` test, and only modify the `col`umn based on the condition of `if`. And, hopefully, you really wanted for those two `printf`'s to be identical. It was hard to see otherwise that they are in fact identical.